# Armature not attaching to mesh

Tags: rigging, armature

I have followed numerous tutorials and this KEEPS happening. When I go into pose mode the left sides of the legs do bend and rotate properly but they bend BOTH legs and the right side legs have no function... I am not understanding, this should be fairly simple. I duplicated the armature from the left to the right, I selected the mesh and then the bones and ctrl+p, with automatic weights and(just as numerous tutorials instruct) and then this happens.
Thank you in advance! [image: aa]

Comment: Are you using a mirror modifier?  For something quick, try applying the mirror mod before parenting to your armature.

Comment: also, let the armature in Pose mode, then select your object and switch to Weight Paint mode to see how each bone acts with the mesh

Comment: Nathan, that was the problem! I didn't apply the mirror and it was mirroring to the other side. You saved me from such a headache, thank you! And moonboots, I looked in weight paint mode and it indeed showed me that one of the leg bones was in control of both legs, I'll utilize that tool next time! Thanks guys!

Comment: Hi, you could write an answer yourself to show and describe what happened and how you solved it. This would help others in the future. Later you could also accept your own answer!